# One errorbar misplaced in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am triying to put errorbar to my graph, but I have some problems with the error bars. Here is my data frame

```
        Condition  congruency Distance Rts liminfRTS limsupRTS   Acc liminfACC limsupACC
 1           Zero     Neutral        0 445       435       455 0.290     0.018     0.039
 2           Zero   Congruent        1 445       435       456 0.023     0.015     0.031
 3           Zero   Congruent        2 441       430       451 0.023     0.014     0.033
 4           Zero   Congruent        3 432       422       442 0.027     0.018     0.036
 5           Zero Incongruent        1 449       439       459 0.034     0.024     0.044
 6           Zero Incongruent        2 449       438       460 0.036     0.024     0.048
 7           Zero Incongruent        3 453       440       465 0.024     0.013     0.035
 8  all different     Neutral        0 446       436       456 0.190     0.013     0.026
 9  all different   Congruent        1 445       434       455 0.028     0.017     0.038
10  all different   Congruent        2 449       438       461 0.021     0.011     0.032
11  all different   Congruent        3 449       438       461 0.031     0.022     0.041
12  all different Incongruent        1 446       436       456 0.024     0.100     0.037
13  all different Incongruent        2 447       436       458 0.020     0.011     0.029
14  all different Incongruent        3 450       440       461 0.019     0.010     0.028
```

I am triying to do a line bar with error bars. The limits of the error bars would be liminfRTS and limsupRTS

```
ggplot(matriz, aes(Distance, Rts, shape= congruency, linetype=congruency))+geom_point(size=5)+geom_line(size=1)+facet_wrap(~Condition, ncol=2)+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = matriz$limsupRT, ymin= matriz$liminfRTS), width=0.25)
```

However, if you look at in the condition all different distance 3, there is error bar which is not placed where it should be. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you use `matriz$` notation in `aes()` of `geom_errorbar()` and that places errorbars in wrong order. In `ggplot()` you shouldn't use `matriz$` inside `aes()` because you have already stated that `matriz` is your data frame and all variables are found there by `ggplot()`.

```
ggplot(matriz, aes(Distance, Rts, shape= congruency, linetype=congruency))+
  geom_point(size=5)+geom_line(size=1)+facet_wrap(~Condition, ncol=2)+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = limsupRTS, ymin= liminfRTS), width=0.25)
```

Comment: I tried the same you proposed but for the variable Acc rathen than RTs, so it would be like: ggplot(matriz, aes(Distance, Acc, shape= congruency, linetype=congruency))+geom_point(size=5)+geom_line(size=1)+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = limsupACC, ymin= liminfACC), width=0.25, linetype=1) +facet_wrap(~Condition, ncol=2)+ theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +theme(axis.line=element_line(), panel.border=element_blank())#+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(400, 500))
 However, the bar errors are again in the wrong place

Comment: Problem is in your data frame - in the first line ACC value is 0.290 but limsupACC values is just 0.039 (it should be more than ACC). Code works as expected, just make your data frame correct way.

Comment: Ops... really stupid question. I am sometimes unable to see these things... Thanks again.